# Running into a 400 error when submitting solutions to the Noops Challenge MazeBot (C#)

Tags: c#, httprequest, http-status-code-400

I'm working on a maze solver for noopschallenge, and they provide a mazebot api. When I submit my answers back, I am receiving a 400 error.

I've made sure that the currentMaze.mazePath append is working, and the URL looks correct but trying to navigate to the url in a browser returns a json object stating that the requested resource was not found.

```cs
public bool checkSolution(List<coordinate> sln)
    {
        string formatted = formatInstructions(sln);

        string url = "https://api.noopschallenge.com" + currentMaze.mazePath;
        solutionJson solutionObj = new solutionJson { directions = formatted };

        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(solutionObj);
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(json);
            streamWriter.Write(json);
        }

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        return true;
    }
```

This ends up returning a 400 error on the line

```cs
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Catch the error, read the body, it probably tells you what's wrong.

Comment: Here is the message: "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Comment: That's the exception. Catch `WebException`, get the exception property `Response` and read the body. It might tell you what's wrong. Either way, `400` is a response generated by the server.

Comment: Thank you! that got it.